# JQuery Mouse Events: How to trigger a callback if the element moves?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseevent

I have the following source:

```
$("body").on('mouseenter', '.tile-2', function () {
  $(".tile-explanation-embarklogo").fadeIn(400)
}).on('mouseleave', '.tile-2', function () {
  $(".tile-explanation-embarklogo").fadeOut("200")
});
```

When the cursor hovers over the element with class `tile-2`, a reveal a hidden div. Accordingly, when the cursor hovers off the element, I hide the div once again.

The problem is that there are times when the the `tile-2` element moves on its own and even disappears (user input can move the `tile-2` element). This is problematic because the cursor never hovers off the element itself and I am unable to hide the div. It stays forever, without being able to remove it.

How can I also call:

`$(".tile-explanation-embarklogo").fadeOut("200")`

when the tile itself moves away from the cursor?

Comment: Instead of mouseleave you could listen for mouseenter for body and check if the element the mouse entered is your title or not. If its not, do the fade out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have your listener on the body tag but try this out:

```
$('.tile-2').on('mouseenter', function() 
{
    $('.tile-explanation-embarklogo').fadeIn(400);
});

$('.tile-2').on('mouseleave', function() 
{
    $('.tile-explanation-embarklogo').fadeOut(200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the hover event also, leaving jquery do th job for you:

```
$('.tile-2').hover(function () {
    $(".tile-explanation-embarklogo").fadeIn(400)
}, function () {
    $(".tile-explanation-embarklogo").fadeOut("200")
});
```